# Given a basis $a_i$ to a space, does knowing $\langle f, a_i \rangle$ for each $i$ determine $f$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $A=\text{span}(a_1, ..., a_n)$ where $a_i$ is a basis (not orthonormal) wrt inner product $\langle ,\rangle$. Suppose $f \in A$.

If I know $\langle f, a_i \rangle$ for each $i$, does that uniquely determine $f$? I think so because we get $n$ equations for $n$ coefficients, but how to prove that those $n$ equations are all "different" to each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you know that $\langle f,a_i \rangle=b_i$ for all $1 \leq i\leq n$. Let $f,g$ be two vectors satisfying these conditions. Hence

$$\langle f,a_i \rangle=\langle g,a_i \rangle $$

for all $1 \leq i\leq n$. Subtracting and using linearity of the inner product gives

$$\langle f-g,a_i \rangle =0$$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$.

But there is only one vector which is perpendicular to all $a_i$...

**EDIT:**

In order to show the existence express $f$ as a linear combination
$$f=f_1 a_1+\dots f_n a_n .$$
Your equations become $$f_1 \langle a_1,a_i \rangle+ \dots+f_i \langle a_i,a_i \rangle + \dots +f_n \langle a_n,a_i \rangle=b_i $$
for $1 \leq i \leq n$. These can be written in matrix form as  $$G \mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b} $$
where $G$ is the [Gram matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix) of the basis vectors. Since it is invertible there is a unique solution for the coefficients $\{f_i \}$.

Comment: Thanks, so you have shown that there is uniqueness. But that doesn't imply that $f$ is well-defined (in the sense that we know what $f$ is) given $\langle f, a_i \rangle$, right?

Comment: @LapLace Edited.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Simply knowing $\left<f,a_i\right>$ is not quite enough to write down the vector $f$.  One also needs to know $\left<a_i, a_j\right>$ for $0\leq i,j,\leq n$.  This is exactly why orthonormal bases are nice.  If $\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis, then $\left<a_i,a_j\right> = \delta_{i,j}$, where $\delta_{i,j} =1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise.  In this case, we have
\begin{equation*}
f = \left<f,a_1\right>a_1 + ...+\left<f,a_n\right>a_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \left< f,a_i\right> a_i.\end{equation*}
It is true, however, as noted in the answer provided by user1337, that $f$ is in fact uniquely determined, but this is still not enough information to write down $f$ in terms of the basis $\{a_1,...,a_n\}$.

Comment: Thanks but are you sure? user's answer contradicts yours.

Comment: @LapLace I don't think there is a contradiction.  It is true that $f$ is uniquely determined by the values of $\left<f,a_i\right>$, but you can't actually express $f$ in terms of the basis $\{a_1,..., a_n\}$ without knowing more information.  In user1337's response, the entries of the Gram matrix are precisely the values $\left<a_i, a_j\right>$, which are unknown.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry for misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be the $n\times n$ matrix with the $a_i$ as columns.  The values $\langle f,a_i\rangle$ are the entries of $M^Tf$.  This determines $f$ because $M$ (and hence $M^T$) is invertible; explicitly,
$$f = (M^T)^{-1} \left[\begin{matrix} \langle f,a_1\rangle \\ \vdots \\ \langle f,a_n\rangle \end{matrix}\right]$$